# Calculating average time difference among items grouped by a specific column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the following dataframe:

```
userid | time     
1        22.01.2001 13:00
1        22.01.2001 13:05   
1        22.01.2001 13:07  
2        22.01.2001 14:00
2        22.01.2001 14:04   
2        22.01.2001 13:05  
2        22.01.2001 13:06  
3        22.01.2001 13:20  
3        22.01.2001 13:22  
4        22.01.2001 13:37
```

What I want to obtain is a new column per user that stores the average time difference among the consecutive activities:

```
userid | avg_time_diff
1        3.5    #(5 + 2) / 2
2        2      #(4 + 1 + 1) / 3
3        2
4        0
```

To achieve this, do I need to loop trough each user and calculate the average time difference one by one? Or, is there a quicker way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following approach:

```
In [84]: df.sort_values('time').groupby('userid')['time'] \
           .apply(lambda x: x.diff().dt.seconds.mean()/60)
Out[84]:
userid
1     3.500000
2    19.666667
3     2.000000
4          NaN
Name: time, dtype: float64
```

Some explanations:

First we sort the DF by `time` column, otherwise we might have negative difference.

Then we group by `userid` and for each group we calculate a time difference for all consecutive rows (sorted) - this will produce a Series of `timedelta64[ns]` dtype, which has an `.dt.seconds` accessor.

Using `.dt.seconds.mean()` we can calculate the average for each group

**UPDATE:**

> take the mean over only the differences that are smaller than 60
>   minutes

```
In [122]: threshold = 60
     ...:
     ...: (df.sort_values('time').groupby('userid')['time']
     ...:    .apply(lambda x: (x.diff().dt.seconds/60)
     ...:                     .to_frame('diff')
     ...:                     .query("diff < @threshold")['diff'].mean()))
     ...:
Out[122]:
userid
1     3.500000
2    19.666667
3     2.000000
4          NaN
Name: time, dtype: float64
```

Comment: thanks. may I ask what would be the type of `x` inside lambda? is it a series of the dates? If so what is the outcome of `.diff()`? I appreciate if you can provide a bit more details so that next time I can do it myself :)

Comment: @renakre, sure! You can check it this way: `df.groupby('userid')['time'].apply(lambda x: print(x.dtypes))` or `df.groupby('userid')['time'].apply(lambda x: print(type(x)))`

Comment: @renakre, i've added an explanation

Comment: Awesome! I got it now. I wonder if it would be easy to take the mean over only the differences that are smaller than 60?

Comment: @renakre, less than 60 minutes or seconds?

Comment: thanks for the update MaxU, but it does not seem to work correctly. The first version works on this dataset  `2014-11-06 22:50:00 |  2014-11-07 20:34:00 | 2014-11-07 20:36:00`. But, it returns `NaN` with the updated version. Thanks for your time, I appreciate it!!!

Comment: Fantastic. So, you first obtained a series of differences, then convert the series to dataframe, and filter the dataframe by the threshold, then take the mean. Is this correct? I learned a lot!!!

Comment: @renakre, yep, this is correct. Glad i could help :)

Comment: could you please check this related question when you get a chance? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44217175/calculating-time-differences-per-group-and-conditionally-multiplying-with-anothe Do you think I will need a different approach?