# Calculating average time difference per group and conditionally multiplying with another column value

Tags: python, pandas

In my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44215230/calculating-average-time-difference-among-items-grouped-by-a-specific-column/), thanks to @MaxU, I was able to calculate the average time difference among datetime values per each user (only if the difference is greater than the given threshold. As a follow-up work, I want to involve another column in this calculation. Let's say I have a length column as well:

```
index | userid | time              | length    
1        1        22.01.2001 13:00    15
2        1        22.01.2001 14:05    12
3        1        22.01.2001 14:07    13
4        2        22.01.2001 13:00    15
5        2        22.01.2001 14:04    12
6        2        22.01.2001 14:05    11
7        2        22.01.2001 14:10    14
8        3        22.01.2001 13:20    18
9        3        22.01.2001 14:25    17
10       4        22.01.2001 13:37    12
```

From this, I can calculate the average time difference among the consecutive activities (`avg_time_diff`) for a threshold of 60 minutes:

```
userid | avg_time_diff
1        2
2        3
3        5
4        0
```

The code for this was:

```
In [122]: threshold = 60
     ...:
     ...: (df.sort_values('time').groupby('userid')['time']
     ...:    .apply(lambda x: (x.diff().dt.seconds/60)
     ...:                     .to_frame('diff')
     ...:                     .query("diff < @threshold")['diff'].mean()))
```

Now, I want to multiple each difference with the corresponding value from the `length` column, and obtain this dataframe:

```
userid | avg_time_diff  | new_column
1        2                26   #(2*13)
2        3                40.5 #(1*11 + 5*14)/2  -> see below for the explanation
3        5                85   #(5*17)
4        0                12   #(since only one row for this user)
```

> Explanation for **40.5 #(1*11 + 5*14)/2** for userid = 2
>
> The time difference (td) between 5th and 4th is discarded since it is
>   larger than 60. `td` between 6th and 5th is **1**. Also, the `length`
>   value on 6th row is **11**. Then, I calculate 1*11= 11. Similarly,
>   `td` between 7th and 6th is **5**. The `length` value on 7th row is
>   **14**. Then, I calculate 5*14= 70. Then, I take the average.

I have been trying to customize the previous code (below), but I think I will need a different approach for this task. Because, with the code below, I do not think I can incorporate the 'length' value inside the `apply` function.

```
In [122]: threshold = 60
     ...:
     ...: (df.sort_values('time').groupby('userid')['time', 'length']
     ...:    .apply(lambda x: (x['time'].diff().dt.seconds/60)
     ...:                     .to_frame('diff')
     ...:                     .query("diff < @threshold")['diff'].mean()))
```

Any suggestions?

**HERE IS MY SOLUTION USING *FOR* LOOP**

```
for student in student_ids:
    df = df_all[df_all['username'] == student]

    df['time_diff'] = pd.DataFrame(df['time'].diff().dt.seconds/60)
    df['time_diff'] = df['time_diff'].fillna(2)#for the first item that has zero time_diff
    df.loc[df['time_diff'] > 60, 'time_diff'] = 60
    df['xxx'] = df['time_diff'] * df['length']
    item = pd.DataFrame(data={'username':[student], 'avg_length':[np.mean(df['xxx'])]})
    my_df = my_df.append(item)
```

Comment: Can you explain this part: `40.5 #(1*11 + 5*14)/2`?

Comment: @MaxU please see the updated post. I have also posted my solution using `for loop`. If you think using loop is not good, happy to see your suggested solution! Thanks again...